# changing the setText value in a fragment from main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been trying to change my textViews text in a fragmentActivity based on whether or not user has clicked the button in the first main activity. I have 2 xml files and 2 .java files and the code at the moment crashes when the app starts.
This is the button code

```
public void getNum(View view) {

        buttonCheck = 1;
        }
```

And this is the code from FragmentTab

```
public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("nothing has been input yet");

    if (FirstActivity.buttonCheck == 1){
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("value");}


    FirstActivity.buttonCheck = 0;
    return v;
}
```

The first error i get from my code from logcat is: "java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ezentertainment.dietabialkowa.FragmentTab.onCreateView(FragmentTab.java:23)" and line 23 is  `tv.setText("nothing has been input yet");`
any help at all is greatly appreciated, I have been fighting with this issue for quite some time now..

tl;dr how to change fragment value based upon input from mainActivity?

**edit:** here is the fragment_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eaecee">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:text="value"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: If findViewById returns null that means that R.id.text could not be found. So double check if you provide the right id for the TextView.
Also... once you found the view, you don't have to call findViewById again in line 26.

Comment: can you post your "fragment_layout" xml? or is there a TextView with id "text" in this xml?

Comment: the id is text im sure it's the right one but i'll post the xml aswell

Comment: The id in the xml seems to be textResult, so try it with TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textResult);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textview id is

> android:id="@+id/textResult"

So, that's why you're getting a null pointer exception.

Also, it's probably a good idea to do a null check when finding a view by ID, just in case something isn't instantiated yet, so it doesn't kill your app.  Something like:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textResult);
if (tv != null){
     tv.setText("nothing has been input yet");
} else {
    // log something if you want.
}
```

Comment: The IDs accessed by findViewById are static final variables inside of a generated file. So including a null check is pointless. If the view is not found you did something wrong and that's why your app should crash.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `setArguement`:

In Activity:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("email", email);
 FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(container, fragment,     tag).addToBackStack(tag).commit();     //please input container and tag yourself
```

In FragmentA:

```
    String email;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null)
       email = bundle.getString("email");

    ...
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the value. then you may need to write a public function in the fragment so that your activity can call it.    eg.  fragment.updateValue("new value");      hope it helps.